# Navigation view handle back button on fragment

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, back

Hi I need to handle back button on fragment. I using this [navigation](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) on my mobile apps. The question is how to handle back button when I open new fragment page?

I try using below code on new fragment.

```
  actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But when click the back button , the navigation will be open. Any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know whenever user presses `Back` button you need to go to the previously loaded fragment and to do that try this (note fragment must be added with  `transaction.addToBackStack(null);`)

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        int backStackCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();//check currently how many frags loaded
        if (backStackCount > 0) {
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(); //go back to previously loaded fragment
        }   
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```